# Grep in R using OR and NOT

Tags: r, regex

I have the following vector in R and I would like to find all the strings containing A's and B's but not the number 2.

```
vec1<-c("A_cont_1", "A_cont_12", "B_treat_8", "AB_cont_22", "cont_21_Aa")
```

The following does not work:

```
grep("A|B|!2", vec1)
```

It gives me back all the strings:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

The same is true for this example:

```
grep("A|B|-2", vec1)
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: do you want to match `( A OR B ) AND NOT 2` or do you want `A OR B OR (NOT 2)`?

Answer (score 41):

You can do this with a fairly simple regular expression:

```
grep("^[^2]*[AB][^2]*$", vec1)
```

In words, it means:

- `^` match the start of the string
- `[^2]*` match anything *except* "2", zero or more times
- `[AB]` match "A" or "B"
- `[^2]*` match anything *except* "2", zero or more times
- `$` match the end of the string

Answer (score 24):

I would use two `grep` calls:

```
intersect(grep("A|B",vec1),grep("2",vec1,invert=TRUE))
#[1] 1 3
```

Comment: or `setdiff(grep('A|B', vec1), grep('2', vec1))`

Answer (score 21):

OP, your attempt is pretty close, try this:

```
grep('^(A|B|[^2])*$', vec1)
```

Comment: This is probably the most compact and yet easy to understand solution. Thanks.

Comment: more general if you like `grep('^(A|B|[^[:digit:]])*$', vec1)`

Comment: Very often, this will yield a different result than @Joshua Ulrich's (an others') answer. So be careful if you apply this to another vector. Depending on what you're after (cf. @Anthony Damico's comment), it might not be what you want. 

For example, `grep('^(A|B|[^2])*$', "yes")` returns `1` (after all, "yes" is a string made entirely of characters that are either A, B, or some character different from 2). 

In contrast, `grep("^[^2]*[AB][^2]*$", yes)` returns `integer(0)`, which seems closer to what you want (unlike the previous regex, @JU's verifies the presence of at least one A or B).

Answer (score 5):

`grep` generally does not work very well for doing a positive and a negative search in one invocation. You might be able to make it work with a complex regular expression, but you might be better off just doing:

```
 grep '[AB]' somefile.txt | grep -v '2'
```

The R equivalent of that would be:

```
grep("2", grep("A|B", vec1, value = T), invert = T)
```

Comment: similar solution for data.frames?

Answer (score 2):

I extended the answer provided by @eddi. I have tested it in R and it works for me. I changed the last variable in your example since they all contained A|B.

```
# Create the vector from the OP with one change
vec1<-c("A_cont_1", "A_cont_12", "B_treat_8", "AB_cont_22", "cont_21_dd")
```

I then ran the following code. It will tell you which results you should expect from each section of grep.

First, tell me which columns contain A or B

```
> grepl("A|B", vec1)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Now tell me which columns contain a "2"

```
> grepl("2", vec1)
[1] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

The index we want is 2,4

```
> grep("2", grep("A|B", vec1, value = T))
[1] 2 4
```

Done!

Comment: This wont work when searching a data.frame as the index information is lost. Is there a similar solution for data.frames?